# Play Console - Advertising ID declaration

Tags: google-play, ads, firebase-analytics, google-advertising-id

here is the scenario. For my app I use some firebase libraries, especially **firebase analytics** which makes use of the **advertising id** through play-services-ads-identifier library.

The question is: since I don't use the advertising id directly but through the firebase sdk, what shall I select here below?

[image]

My doubt is: I know why I'm using firebase analytics, but I don't know why it uses the advertising id!

Anyone with the same doubt? what have you selected?

thanks in advance

Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same doubt about what to do as you are. I was not declaring the AD_ID explicitly in my manifest, but the merged manifest included the AD_ID, so I commented out the Firebase libraries in my gradle file and synced. Looking at the merged manifest file after syncing the AD_ID permission was no longer included. I opted to select "Yes" to using the AD_ID since it was in the merged manifest and opted to select "Analytics" as I am using Firebase for analytics. I hope this helps some.

Comment: At the end I did the same. Thank you!